# Mongodb + Yii2 ошибка “Detected corrupt BSON data”

Tags: yii2, mongodb

Когда делаю aggregate в Yii2 я получаю ошибку "Detected corrupt BSON data"

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('company');
        $result = $collection->aggregate(array(
                array(
                    '$group' => array(
                        '_id' => ['$substr' => ['$name', 0, 1]],
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
```

Но если запустить в консоли, то все работает нормально

```
db.company.aggregate([{$group : {_id : {$substr: ["$name", 0,1]}}}])
```

Как исправить?